# Answer review - is it really answered question?

Tags: discussion, support, review, low-quality-posts

I have seen many times [these type of explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/796667) were people addressed only page number of a book.

What should I do during a review? Should I flag answers as low quality or not an answer or skip?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ask the answerer in a comment to expand their answer a bit, and explain that the idea of the site is that in general an answer is not just a link or a reference to a source that gives an actual answer. Yet, at least for the time being, I would let the answer stand; it does appear to provide some potentially useful information (the reference is quite precise, with page numbers even).

The above applies especially in this case, where the answer was given by a new user who could not comment (I think the information given, would be a perfectly good comment) and they may very well not be familiar with the standards of the site.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.